# Intersecting overlapping intervals in Java

Tags: java, intersection, intervals

I have an input set of date ranges that may overlap. Instead of combining these overlapping date ranges, I want to create new date ranges with adjusted dates, e.g.:

```
|---------------------–|
        |-----| 
            |--------------–|
```

should end up in:

```
|-------|---|-|--------|----|
```

Is there an efficient way to solve this with Java?

Thanks in advance!

**UPDATE:**
I didn't mention my own approach in my first question, so here it is: I'd simply take the start and the end date of an interval and add it to a sorted set. Afterwards I'd  iterate over the set and create new intervals based on re-ordered dates.

Comment: It looks like all you want to do is take the start and end dates and sort them. Does that solve your problem?

Comment: ok, sorry @JREN My approach would be to simply take the start and the end date of an interval and add it to a sorted set. Afterwards I'd simply iterate over the set and create new intervals based on re-ordered dates.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To solve such problem, sort your intervals using start date as first criteria and end date as second. This way you can intersect the intervals in a single iteration. If your interval is overlapped by another interval that starts no sooner, then its successor in the sorted order should be an overlapping interval and so on.

Comment: I imagine dealing with overlap with this algorithm could end up being rather complicated.

Comment: Actually not really. You only check the end of the current interval against the beginning of the next interval in the ordering. I have written this algorithm many times and it is not hard at all IMHO.

Comment: In the example in the question, you need to keep track of the end of the first interval after partially processing both the second and third. It's not too complicated, but I believe it would require an additional data structure for the end points. [Splitting up the intervals into start and end points from the start](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17543207/1711796) would be simpler.

Answer (score 6):

You could use [Guava's Range](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/RangesExplained) support. Haven't used it with Date objects but it could work.
Combined with [RangeSet](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/NewCollectionTypesExplained#RangeSet) you could add all date ranges and then check if a Date is in the ranges, get the complete range, etc.

Answer (score 6):

The basic idea:

- Split up each interval into start and end points
- Sort the points
- Iterate through the points and create the new intervals between all neighbouring points.
  Keep track of `startIntervals - endIntervals` and whenever this number is 0, there should be no interval in that range.

Answer (score 2):

Using my time library [Time4J](https://github.com/MenoData/Time4J), following convenient solution is possible without much brainstorming about the real implementation:

```
// create the intervals
SimpleInterval<Date> i1 = SimpleInterval.between(new Date(0L), new Date(5000L));
SimpleInterval<Date> i2 = SimpleInterval.between(new Date(0L), new Date(7000L));
SimpleInterval<Date> i3 = SimpleInterval.between(new Date(1000L), new Date(2000L));

// collect the intervals
IntervalCollection<Date> icoll =
    IntervalCollection.onTraditionalTimeLine().plus(i3).plus(i2).plus(i1);

// split and iterate
for (ChronoInterval<Date> interval : icoll.withSplits().getIntervals()) {
    System.out.println(interval);
}
```

Output:

```
[Thu Jan 01 01:00:00 CET 1970/Thu Jan 01 01:00:01 CET 1970)
[Thu Jan 01 01:00:01 CET 1970/Thu Jan 01 01:00:02 CET 1970)
[Thu Jan 01 01:00:02 CET 1970/Thu Jan 01 01:00:05 CET 1970)
[Thu Jan 01 01:00:05 CET 1970/Thu Jan 01 01:00:07 CET 1970)
```

The main adjustment after defining and gathering all the intervals is just calling [withSplits()](http://time4j.net/javadoc-en/net/time4j/range/IntervalCollection.html#withSplits--) on the interval collection.

Another advantage is the option to slightly adjust the code such that working with other types like the class `java.time.Instant` from Java-8 or the built-in Time4J-types like `Moment`, `PlainDate`, `PlainTimestamp` etc. is easily possible, too.

Answer (score 1):

## Using java.time

Let's use the modern java.time classes.

The [`LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html) class represents a date-only value without time-of-day and without time zone.

Create a little class `DateRange` to hold the stop and start dates.

```
public class DateRange {
    public LocalDate start , stop ;

    public DateRange ( LocalDate start , LocalDate stop ) {
        if(stop.isBefore(start)){
            throw new IllegalArgumentException ("The stop date is before the start date." );
        }
        this.start = start;
        this.stop = stop;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString () {
        return "DateRange{ " + "start=" + start + ", stop=" + stop + " }";
    }

}
```

Instantiate objects of that class, and collect.

```
    List<DateRange> ranges = new ArrayList<> ( 3 );
    ranges.add ( new DateRange ( LocalDate.of ( 2017 , Month.JANUARY , 17 ) , LocalDate.of ( 2017 , Month.MARCH , 7 ) ) );
    ranges.add ( new DateRange ( LocalDate.of ( 2017 , Month.FEBRUARY , 12 ) , LocalDate.of ( 2017 , Month.FEBRUARY , 16 ) ) );
    ranges.add ( new DateRange ( LocalDate.of ( 2017 , Month.FEBRUARY , 14 ) , LocalDate.of ( 2017 , Month.MARCH , 25 ) ) );

    System.out.println ( "ranges: " + ranges );
```

Extract each start and each stop, collecting into a `List`.

```
    // Intersect and combine to create a sequence of new DateRange objects.
    // Collect each start & stop as individual `LocalDate` objects.
    List<LocalDate> dates = new ArrayList<> ( ranges.size () * 2 );
    for ( DateRange range : ranges ) {
        dates.add ( range.start );
        dates.add ( range.stop );
    }
```

Sort the dates. As shown in the Question, the various ranges may overlap with one another. We need them in chronological order so as to make new abutting date ranges.

```
    // Sort the collection of dates.
    Collections.sort ( dates );
```

Loop the sorted dates, using each as a start date and the following date as the stop.

```
    // Loop the sorted dates, creating DateRange objects as we go.
    List<DateRange> rangesOutput = new ArrayList<> ( dates.size () ); // Not an exact initial capacity but good enough.
    for ( int i = 1 ; i < dates.size () ; i ++ ) {
        LocalDate start = dates.get ( i - 1 ); // Subtract one for silly index counting.
        LocalDate stop = dates.get ( i + 1 - 1 ); // Subtract one for silly index counting. Or use ( i ) instead.
        if (  ! start.equals ( stop ) ) {  // If not equal, proceed. (If equal, ignore and move on to next loop.)
            DateRange range = new DateRange ( start , stop );
            rangesOutput.add ( range );
        }
    }
    System.out.println ( "rangesOutput: " + rangesOutput );
```

When run.

> ranges: [DateRange{ start=2017-01-17, stop=2017-03-07 }, DateRange{ start=2017-02-12, stop=2017-02-16 }, DateRange{ start=2017-02-14, stop=2017-03-25 }]
>
> rangesOutput: [DateRange{ start=2017-01-17, stop=2017-02-12 }, DateRange{ start=2017-02-12, stop=2017-02-14 }, DateRange{ start=2017-02-14, stop=2017-02-16 }, DateRange{ start=2017-02-16, stop=2017-03-07 }, DateRange{ start=2017-03-07, stop=2017-03-25 }]

See this [code live at IdeOne.com](http://ideone.com/jBqmOB).

---

## About java.time

The [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [Oracle Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8) and [**SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9) and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - The [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts *ThreeTen-Backport* (mentioned above) for Android specifically.
  - See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [ThreeTen-Extra](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).